# Starting point of a swipe event in Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, ios, hammer.js

Is there a way to find out the start point of a swipe gesture with Hammer.js? I need to know it in order to find out if someone started swiping from the border of the device (an iPad in this case).

```
        $(".nav").on("swipeleft", function(ev) {
            console.log(ev);
        });
```

I printed the whole Event-Object to the console, but only found the "center" coordinates. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(e.changedPointers[0].screenX-e.deltaX);
```

that will get you the starting x position. replace x with y for y position.

Answer (score -1):

In the event look for evt.touches[0].

Here you will find x and y values.

If you're not using jQuery. I found the x and y values in

evt.gesture.startEvent.touches[0]